What is your favorite meme about UX design?
Just share your favorite meme and feel free to explain why you chose it.
I chose this meme because, in design, functionality and the needs of users should come first, with beauty being secondary.

Source: https://uxdworld.com/20-famous-design-memes-to-make-you-laugh/
